# I'd like the following simple vbs file converted into a batch file .bat

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'd like the following simple vbs file converted into a batch file .bat
I've tried numerous converters, all of which have failed.
I'd like the message to play in the batch file at a certain point, just after the file is launched.

```
Dim speaks, speech
speaks="Welcome to your PC, %USERNAME%"
Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
speech.Speak speaks
```

Comment: Why convert to a batch file when you can simply run the VBScript file directly? If it's part of a larger script, it would make more sense to convert the whole thing to VBScript (or PowerShell) so you don't keep running into batch file limitations.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can write something like that in order to generate your vbs file and execute it with a batch file:

---

```
@echo off
Title Speak IT !
Set "Msg=Welcome to your PC, %USERNAME% !"
echo(
echo "%Msg%"
Call :SpeakIT "%Msg%"
Pause>nul & Exit /B
:SpeakIT <Msg>
::-----------------------------------------------
(
echo    Dim speaks, speech
echo    speaks="%~1"
echo    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice"^)
echo    speech.Speak speaks
)>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
Cscript //Nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: One other question. Is it possible to change the voice?